# HMAC Binary Digest Node vs Ruby

Tags: node.js, ruby, encoding, hmac

I am trying to implement a Node API using Ruby documentation (ugh). The issue specifically is around verifying a secret, which is put through an HMAC digest and then base64 encoded.

I can't seem to get the two to equate. Here are the same snippets in Node & Ruby:

*Note*: The below can also be viewed online via repl.it:

- Ruby (https://repl.it/repls/SarcasticSpottedSymbol)
- Node (https://repl.it/repls/AncientQuarrelsomeWearable)

### Node

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let text = 'example';
let key  = '123';

let h = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(text).digest('binary');
Buffer.from(h).toString('base64');
# => 'acKNVMOwSUUowqdZw7HCnMKOwofCqcO5wp51wqXCiBvCkmfDrjkmwrzDtizCmS3ChMK6'
```

### Ruby

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

text = 'example'
key  = '123'

h = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, text)
Base64.strict_encode64(h)
# => 'aY1U8ElFKKdZ8ZyOh6n5nnWliBuSZ+45Jrz2LJkthLo='
```

Switching both over to hex works, e.g.

*Node*

```
crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(text).digest('hex')
```

*Ruby*

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, text)
```

Unfortunately it isn't up to me to switch to hex - the web service uses the ruby code to sign.

Looking up the ruby docs for [`OpenSSL::HMAC.digest`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html) states:

> Returns the authentication code as a *binary string*.

Just outputting the result from the HMAC, I can't tell whether this is a difference or just a rendering issue:

*Node*

```
crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(text).digest('binary');
# => 'iTðIE(§Yñ©ùu¥\u001bgî9&¼ö,-º'
```

*Ruby*

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, text)
# => "i\x8DT\xF0IE(\xA7Y\xF1\x9C\x8E\x87\xA9\xF9\x9Eu\xA5\x88\e\x92g\xEE9&\xBC\xF6,\x99-\x84\xBA"
```

How can I get these two to equate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By not inputting any specific encoding to Node's digest method, the raw unicode buffer is output - matching Ruby's.

This is the end result:

```
crypto = require('crypto');

text = 'example';
key  = '123';

h = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(text).digest();
Buffer.from(h).toString('base64');
```

Who would've thought - you could just pass nothing into the method...

Answer (score 0):

To get Ruby to output Base64:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

text = 'example'
key  = '123'

Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, text))
# "aY1U8ElFKKdZ8ZyOh6n5nnWliBuSZ+45Jrz2LJkthLo=\n"
```

You can delete the `\n` newlines and trailing padding if you want.